# IF $A$ and $B$ are disconnected in $\mathbb{R}^2$, does it follow that $A \cup B $ is not connected?

Tags: general-topology

I was thinking if we take $A = \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{y = 1\}$ which is disconnected, and $B = \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{y = 2\} $ which is also disconnected, but $A \cup B = \mathbb{R}^2$ which is connected. Can someone think of other examples? thanks

Comment: $\Bbb R^2\setminus\Bbb R=\Bbb R^2$, since $\Bbb R$ is not a subset of $\Bbb R^2$. I suspect that you mean $\Bbb R^2\setminus(\Bbb R\times\{0\})$ or some such subset of $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: will $B = \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{y = 2\} $

Comment: $A=\{(x,y):\;|x|=1\}$ and $B=\{(x,y):\;|y|=1\}$ are disconnected. However $A\cup B$ es connected.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott R is not subset of R^2 ? can you explain this please?

Comment: The set $\mathbb R$ is not, but the set $\mathbb R \times \{0\}$ (which as a subspace is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$) is. Remember that elements in $\mathbb R^2$ are ordered pairs of real numbers and elements in $\mathbb R$ are single real numbers.

Comment: The elements of $\Bbb R^2$ are ordered pairs of real numbers, and the elements of $\Bbb R$ are real numbers. An ordered pair of real numbers is not a real number. $\Bbb R^2\cap\Bbb R=\varnothing$: there is nothing that is both a real number and an ordered pair of real numbers. The $x$-axis in $\Bbb R^2$ is $\Bbb R\times\{0\}$, not $\Bbb R$.

Comment: I see. I get it know. thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the easiest examples builds on the fact that $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$ provide such an example in $\Bbb R$: just use $\Bbb Q\times\Bbb R$ and $(\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q)\times\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 3):

An easy to visualize counterexample can be formed from $S^1$. The section of $S^1$ lying in the first and third quadrants is a disconnected space, as is the section of $S^1$ lying in the second and fourth quadrants. But their union is all of $S^1$. To put this more formally, the subspace $A = \left(\{(x, y)\ |\ x \geq 1, y \geq 1\}  \cap S^1\right) \cup \left(\{(x, y)\ |\ x \leq 1, y \leq 1\} \cap S^1\right)$ is disconnected, as is the subspace $ B = \left(\{(x, y)\ |\ x \leq 1, y \geq 1\} \cap S^1\right) \cup \left(\{(x, y)\ |\ x \geq 1, y \leq 1\} \cap S^1\right)$. But $A \cup B = S^1$ is connected.